# Adding model list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of the List of Request Types. With the For cycle, I have data from the vertaban. I want to add the dates into detail.

There is an error in the code I wrote. All data are listed as the same.

```
public IHttpActionResult TalepListele(TalepList model)
{
    List<TalepList> detay = new List<TalepList>();
    using (var ctx = new ktdbEntities())
    {
        var query = ctx.talepListele(model.KullaniciId, 0, 10).ToList();
        var adet = query.Count;
        if (query.Count != 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < adet; i++)
            {
                model.OlusturmaTarihi = query[i].olusturulmaTarihi;
                model.TalepDurumAdi = query[i].talepDurumuAdi;
                model.TalepDurumId = query[i].talepTuruID;
                model.TalepTuruAdi = query[i].talepTuruAdi;
                model.TalepTuruId = query[i].talepTuruID;
                model.talepID = query[i].talepID;
                detay.Add(model);
            }
            return Ok(detay);
        }
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code and you should learn beetween reference type and value type differents.

```
 public IHttpActionResult TalepListele(TalepList model)
    {
        List<TalepList> detay = new List<TalepList>();
        using (var ctx = new ktdbEntities())
        {
            var query = ctx.talepListele(model.KullaniciId, 0, 10).ToList();
            var adet = query.Count;

                for (var i = 0; i < adet; i++)
                {
                TalepList talep = new TalepList();
                talep.OlusturmaTarihi = query[i].olusturulmaTarihi;
                talep.TalepDurumAdi = query[i].talepDurumuAdi;
                talep.TalepDurumId = query[i].talepTuruID;
                talep.TalepTuruAdi = query[i].talepTuruAdi;
                talep.TalepTuruId = query[i].talepTuruID;
                talep.talepID = query[i].talepID;
                    detay.Add(talep);
                }
                return Ok(detay);

        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same instance of `TalepList` to `detay` multiple times.

```
for (var i = 0; i < adet; i++)
{
  TalepList mdl = new TalepList();
  mdl.OlusturmaTarihi = query[i].olusturulmaTarihi;
  ...
  detay.Add(mdl);
}
```